# Force Laravel to Ignore Exception

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

When the below code, PHP should catch the exception and continue execution without throwing any error/exception page.

**Question:** However with Laravel 4, the exception page shows up. Setting `app.debug` to `false` only hides the stack trace. How do you force Laravel to ignore and continue execution?

```
 try
  {
      SomeOperation();
  }
  catch (SomeException $e)
  {
      // do nothing... php will ignore and continue    
  }
```

Answer (score 16):

That can be a namespace problem.

Did you try to put a slash before the exception?

```
catch(\Exception $e)
{
   Log::error($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: what is the namespace required to handle exceptions in Laravel? I'm using phpstorm and I noticed that it suggested a few different libraries to hande the "exception", and I'm not sure I always chose the right one. What I want is to handle things through various try catch blocks, and in case things fail to log the error but continue the operation

Comment: This took a very long time to figure out why artisan appeared to be ignoring the try/catch block. I never would have have thought about this on on my own.